# Changing of variable in a distribution defined by a convolution

Tags: probability, convolution, change-of-variable

Let $f$, $g$, and $h$ denote probability distributions such that $$f(x) = \int_0^x g(x')h(x-x')~dx'$$ where $x$ only takes non-negative values. Now, suppose we want to perform a change of variable from $x$ to $y=q(x)$ in the above equation. My question is: how does the convolution equation change when we perform the change of variables. In other words, after changing the variable to $y$, suppose the distributions corresponding to $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are $F(y)$, $G(y)$, and $H(y)$, then can we write the equation satisfied by $F$, $G$, and $H$?

Take for example $y=\log x$. Here is my attempt:
We can see that $F(y) = e^yf(e^y)$ where $F(y)$ denotes the distribution of $y$ obtained by performing a change of variable $x$ to $y$ in $f$. Similarly, we define $y' = \log x'$, and write $G(y') = e^{y'}g(e^{y'})$. Now we come to the the part where I am facing some difficulty: dealing with $h(x-x')$.

Approach:

Define $z = x-x'$, and $w = \log z$. Now, $h(z) = H(w)e^{-w}$, and substituting $w = \ln(e^y - e^{y'})$ allows us to write
$$h(x-x') = \frac{H(\ln(e^y - e^{y'}))}{e^y-e^{y'}}$$

This would mean, our original convolution can now be written as:
$$e^{-y}F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{e^y} e^{-y'}G(y')\cdot\frac{H(\ln(e^y - e^{y'}))}{e^y-e^{y'}}~ e^{y'} dy'$$ which gives $$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{e^y} e^{y}~G(y')\cdot \frac{H(\ln(e^y - e^{y'}))}{e^y-e^{y'}}~ dy'.$$

Here, I have literally written each term in the first equation in terms of the corresponding distribution of $y$. Does this seem correct? If not, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking and what you are trying to do

Comment: @Masacroso I am trying to understand how the convolution equation changes, after I perform a change of variables. To make it more clear, I have taken the specific example of changing the variable x to y=log(x), and then writing the convolution equation in terms of F, G, and H, which are the distributions obtained after changing the variable, corresponding to the distributions f, g, and h respectively. Does that make it more clear? If yes, I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: In your example $y$ is a function of $x$ but there's no mention of that elsewhere in your question.  Changing the variable from $x$ to $y$ is as simple as writing $y$ wherever you have $x$ (noting that $x'$ is not $x$ and so doesn't change.  What do you *actually* want to ask?

Comment: @postmortes I have added the fact that $y=q(x)$, and is not just a change of notation. I hope it is now clear. I think I also realise that I have made a mistake in writing $h(x-x')$ correctly in terms of $H$.

Comment: That's a great improvement :)  I've upvoted.

Comment: @Masacroso I have added some more detail in the question, and have posted my attempt at a possible solution. Is it better now?

Comment: This looks fine. It looks singular but this is only apparent, since $H(w)=e^wf(w)$ goes (sufficiently) fast to zero as $w\to -\infty$. Are you worried about something particular?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Thanks a lot for the feedback! In a previous version of this question, I had performed the change of variables incorrectly. Even I am confident that this seems correct now, but I still wanted some more eyes on this. In various problems, I regularly come across convolutions, and students are trained to directly perform some transform like Laplace or Fourier, which simplifies the problem quite a bit.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh However, I just wanted to see how the convolution equation is modified during a change of variables. Instead of taking a Laplace/Fourier transform, can a change of variables end up simplifying the problem in any way?

Comment: It probably depends, but in I don't think so. Convolution is almost the simplest possible operation, calculating the distribution of the sum of two random variables. Your example does not look simplifying as it calculates the distribution of $X=\ln(e^Y+e^Z)$ (my notation has no relation with yours). On the other hand if you make the inverse transform of your example (replace $y=\log x$ by $x=\log y$) it corresponds to the distribution of a product $X=YZ$ which is of interest.